# What does this access query actually delete?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

```
DELETE A.*, B.cID, A.capacity
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.cID = B.cID
WHERE (((B.cID) Is Null) AND ((A.capacity)="r"));
```

Sadly this is a project that I am working on and I am trying to convert this to SQL to run on sql server.

Only problem is, i don't know what deleting Table.Column does..it doesn't work in sql server
What does including B.cID and A.Capacity in the Delete statement do?

Comment: Try it and find out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that will delete rows from A that

- do not have a matching row in B, and
- have capacity equal to "r".

If I'm right about that, I think this statement is equivalent.

```
delete from a 
where a.cid not in (select cid from B)
  and a.capacity = 'r';
```

Although the statement with the left join is less readable at first, it usually performs a lot better. For SQL Server, you can test this query, too.

```
delete from a
left join b on a.cid = b.cid
where b.cid is null 
  and a.capacity = 'r';
```

Make sure the two queries have the same result, then look at the execution plan for each version to see which performs better, and why.

DELETE statements delete rows. They don't delete values from columns while leaving the row otherwise intact. (I'm pretty sure that's what's confusing you about the original syntax.)